# Cross-browser vs. multi-browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between cross-browser javascript and multi-browser javascript? Do cross-browser and multi-browser mean the same thing?

Wikipedia link at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-browser mentions "multi-browser" to some extent but it seems to be unverified information. At some places people have used it to mean the same thing. So, I am bit confused.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Try Googling `multi-browser javascript`, you will get the answer.

Comment: The answer appears to be the first sub-section of the wiki page you've linked to - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-browser#Cross-browser_vs._multi-browser

Comment: Reading that reminded me of: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman . I am sure there is a point and a distinction to be made, but I am not sure what it is.

Comment: Cross-browser means something that works across all browsers whereas multi-browser means something that works on, well, multiple browsers. You'll often see people cursing IE for lack of some or the other feature on articles which use latest CSS3 styles to achieve something wonderful. The solutions they present are multi-browser. When those solutions will start working on IE(in a year or so), they will be called cross-browser. Is there a yardstick to define them? - No. They are notions and not standards and will remain so.

Comment: @Chandranshu: I think this would make a great answer, even if the question might seem to be subjective.

Comment: @FelixKling - I didn't capture it as an answer because I thought sooner or later, this question would be deleted anyway. Let me do it now.

Answer (score 2):

*Capturing my comment as an answer as suggested by FelixKling.*

Cross-browser means something that works across all browsers whereas multi-browser means something that works on, well, multiple browsers.

You'll often see people cursing IE for lack of some or the other feature on articles which use latest CSS3 styles to achieve something wonderful. The solutions they present are multi-browser. When those solutions will start working on IE(in a year or so), they will be called cross-browser.

Is there a yardstick to define these terms? - No. They are notions and not standards and will remain so since anyone can whip up a browser with minimal support for all of standards.